# How can I resolve collisions at different speeds, depending on the direction?

Tags: xna, c#, collision-detection, collision-resolution

I have, for all intents and purposes, a Triangle class that objects in my scene can collide with (In actuality, the right side of a parallelogram).

My collision detection and resolution code works fine for the purposes of preventing a gameobject from entering into the space of the Triangle, instead directing the movement along the edge.

[image]

The trouble is, the maximum speed along the x and y axis is not equivalent in my game, and moving along the Y axis (up or down) should take twice as long as an equivalent distance along the X axis (left or right).

Unfortunately, these speeds apply to the collision resolution too, and movement along the blue path above progresses twice as fast. What can I do in my collision resolution to make sure that the speedlimit for Y axis movement is obeyed in the latter case?

Collision Resolution for this case below (vecInput and velocity are the position and velocity vectors of the game object):

```
// y = mx+c
// solve for y. M = 2, x = input's x coord, c = rightYIntercept
lowY =  2*vecInput.x + parag.rightYIntercept ;

...

else
{
    // y = mx+c
    // vecInput.y = 2(x) + RightYIntercept
    // (vecInput.y - RightYIntercept) / 2 = x;

    //if velocity.Y (positive) greater than velocity.X (negative)
    //pushing from bottom, so push right.
    if(velocity.y > -1*velocity.x)
    {
            //change the input vector's x position to match the
            //y position on the shape's edge. Formula for line: Y = MX+C
            // M is 2, C is rightYIntercept, y is the input y, solve for X.
        vecInput = new Vector2((vecInput.y - parag.rightYIntercept)/2, vecInput.y);
        Debug.Log("adjusted rightwards");
    }
    else
    {
        vecInput = new Vector2( vecInput.x, lowY);
            Debug.Log("adjusted downwards");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to provide a little bit more information about what those variables mean. for example what is `RightYIntercept`?

Comment: @Gajet Hm. In retrospect, you're probably right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming `vecInput` is your final result for this problem I suggest you add 4 lines of code at the end of your code. checking if you the results exceed in either x axis value or y axis value.

```
if (math.Abs(vecInput.x) > MaxXSpeed)
    vecInput *= maxXSpeed / vecInput.x;
if (math.Abs(vecInput.y) > MaxYSpeed)
    vecInput *= maxYSpeed / vecInput.y;
```